# splunk HEC endpoint is execting priv key

Tags: fluent-plugin-splunk-hec

when interacting HEC endpoint even priv key is expected ?

dr % curl --cert splunkserverdefaultcert-chain.crt https://-splunkhec.:8088/services/collector
curl: (58) unable to set private key file: 'splunkserverdefaultcert-chain.crt' type PEM

splunkserverdefaultcert-chain.crt -- is downloaded from https://-splunkhec.:8088/services/collector .

Why is the priv key needed to interact with HEC endpoint on splunk

I am expecting to be able interact with only certificate  chain